# WPF/Silverlight which to start learning first?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I am a 6-years .Net Developer, and want to know which is better to start learning first, Silverlight or WPF.

I know this question seems a little-bit argumentative but since Silverlight is a mini-version of WPF. I think this takes away the argumentation.

So in the light of that, if I considered start learning:

**Silverlight First:** Because it would be easier to learn than its big brother.

**WPF First:** Because it would be easier to know the basic concepts and event-model of WPF before moving to SL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight will be fused with WPF in a couple of years.

Study Silverlight first, i recommend the book Pro Silverlight 4 in C# from Apress, the unique that have color pages.

If in future you'll need some extra Windows functions, go to the much complete WPF.

With Silverlight you can also develop Windows phone 7 applications, and Xbox 360 (rumored). In windows 8 will be a Silverlight Marketplace (valid rumor), and you can create very rich applications / part of website / full websites instead of using the slow, crappy and "browser inconstistent" JQuery+Canvas that have no tools at all for design (and when it will have, Silvelight 5 will have real 3D and better tools).
Also the fact to use the same language for client and server is priceless.

Comment: Do you have any references on "Silverlight will be fused with WPF"? What does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Learn Silverlight first so you won't be annoyed that you cannot use useful things like `RelativeSource` and `x:Static` in Silverlight :P

Comment: ..and MultiBinding.. and DataType for DataTemplate.. and PlacementTarget for Popup.. and.. VisualBrush.. and.. Everytime I use Silverlight (and I mean everytime) I find another useful feature missing :) SL 5 seems promising though

Answer (score 2):

Well Silverlight and WPF is "pretty much" the same actually.  As you said Silverlight has only a subset of the .NET framework but it doesn't make it "simpler" than WPF.

The biggest leap you will have to make in order to learn those languages is **learning XAML**, which is the same in both.

It all depends on what you need to do.  Do you want to publish your project to the web, then go with silverlight (you can do a XBAP project in WPF to publish it to the web, but clients will need Full .NET Framework).  If you need advanced .NET functionnality, then use WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight first. It is easier to add the extra WPF features than to unlearn things when doing WPF first.

Having said that, it doesn't matter that much. There is more on Silverlight on the web these days.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of applications do you want to write ?  Desktop applications that need local access or web based applications ?

If it is a matter of learning, I would learn both in parallel.  Keeping your application consistent to run in both run times will force you to learn all of the little differences.  Once you get past the main SilverLight features, shift into the features only provided by WPF (though I would start with the libraries likely to be included with SL5, first, such as 3D).

Answer (score 1):

Go with Silverlight first, although it is not as feature rich as WPF it is simpler. Also Microsoft are actively evolving the platform. Silverlight is not a true subset of WPF as it had things like a DataGrid control first.

Good learning resource: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/ together with the Pro Silverlight book which you already have.

The further advantage of starting with Silverlight is that it will be easier to develop for the new Windows phone (broadly it uses an older version of Silverlight).

Answer (score 0):

Learn both at the same time! Not one or the other, but both. There's plenty of overlap between the two technologies which should make it more practical to focus on both at once.